# How to change seconds into HH:MM:SS format in C++?

Tags: c++

So I have a function that returns the seconds between the range 0 and 86400 (24 hours). My goal is to take those seconds and return the hours, remaining minutes (between 0 and 60), and remaining seconds (between 0 and 60).

```
// What i have tried:

    hour = timeInSeconds / 3600;
    min = timeInSeconds / 60; // this is returning total minutes (which i dont want)
    sec = timeInSeconds % 60;
```

The main problem im having is with the minutes because they go above 60.

For example, if i make the time = 35000 seconds, i will get the hours to be 9 but my minutes will be around 853.

Therefore this is how my output looks like:

```
17:0853:33 // How can i get remaining minutes? This returns to me total minutes.
```

So i guess, What im asking is how do i get the **left over minutes** from the total seconds after the hours have been calculated?

Comment: You somehow ended up with seconds that are ranged 0-59. If you ponder exactly how you accomplished this feat, the answer as to how to accomplish the same with the minute values should be obvious, then.

Comment: Just needed that motivation lol

Answer (score 2):

```
min = ((timeInSeconds % 3600) / 60)
```

Just needed to think a little bit more

Comment: this is far much better

Answer (score 0):

```
hour = timeInSeconds / 3600;
min = (timeInSeconds - hour * 3600) / 60;
sec = timeInSeconds  - hour * 3600 - min * 60;
```